# Postfix bcc to ldap address

Tags: email, active-directory, postfix

I am using Postfix with AD, and I want to send a copy of every email to their manager. Therefore I have these entries:

```
cn: staff1
mail: staff1@company.com
manager: CN=Manager1,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=com
```

and I want every email from and to staff1 bcc to

```
cn: Manager1
mail: manager1@company.com
manager: CN=Director,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=com
```

and every mail manager1 receives or sent bcc to

```
cn: Director
mail: director@company.com
```

how can I implement that? Do I have to use always_bcc? how?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry.. found it a few moment after I posted this question. This is my manager bcc cf

```
server_host = ad.company.com
search_base = cn=users,dc=company,dc=com
version = 3
scope = sub
query_filter = (userPrincipalName=%s)
result_attribute = mail
special_result_attribute = manager
bind = yes
bind_dn = cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=company,dc=com
bind_pw = xxxxxxxx
```